# get backend to front end

Tags: tinymce, uploads, front-end

im trying to mashup [this german have gotten it to work with tinymce](http://blog.murawski.ch/2011/10/wordpress-backend-editor-tinymce-im-frontend-einbinden/)

im trying ti mash it up with [this get posting from to the front end](http://new2wp.com/labs/downloads/New_Post_Forn_by-Jared_New2WP.txt)

would be glad if someone has done similar things or guide me in some direction

Comment: Please rewrite your question. We have no idea what you're trying to accomplish and no idea how you want to "mash up" these different resources.  As it stands, -1 for an incredibly unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

If fixed it with the great plugin from http://formidablepro.com site

Answer (score 0):

Add my Class which I provided in the article, then at your own site add on the end:

echo do_shortcode('[wuktinymce fields="description"]');

then your textarea "description" will be TinyMCE featured

Comment: I have gone with the formidable pro. works for the developmen im doing